# What's the difference among とばかりに, (と言わ)んばかりにand かのごとく?

Tags: grammar

Hi what's the difference between these three forms?. I have made some research but they all seem to mean "As if". In the specific, とばかりに appears to mean "As to say", (と言わ)んばかりに "As he/she wanted to say" and  かのごとく "As if". Can you explain me how to use them correctly?

Comment: It might help if you further reveal the findings of your research and provide some example sentences.

Answer (score 4):

You have almost answered your question already. とばかりに follows someone's statement, feeling, etc., because this と is a quotative particle. It means "as if to say."

> - やれやれとばかりに振り返った。
> - よく聞いてくれたとばかりに話し始めた。
> - 信じられないとばかりに目を見開いた。
> - そのことを当然(だ)とばかりに受け入れていた。

You can even use brackets with とばかりに:

> 「信じられない」とばかりに目を見開いた。

(まるで)～かのごとく is just "as if":

> - バネに弾かれたかのごとく立ち上がった。
> - 体が鉛でできているかのごとく重い。
> - そのことを当然であるかのごとく受け入れていた。

Comment: Sorry could you also insert some examples of んばかりに？ I edited the post because originally I have written two times にばかりに,  instead of んばかりに. 