# Meaning of だとでもいうかの

Tags: grammar

I found this sentence, in which I'm not quite sure about the `だとでもいうかの` part:

> ところがどういうわけか神町駅前には客待ちのタクシーが一台も停まっていなかった。その代わり**だとでもいうかの**ごとく、駅前広場には何台もの自転車が置かれてあって（そこは駐輪場なのだから当たり前のことなのだが!）、トーマス井口が周囲をキョロキョロと見回しているうちに人気{ひとけ}もばったり無くなってしまった。

I found [this](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/56142/%EF%BD%9E%E3%81%A8%E3%81%A7%E3%82%82%E3%81%84%E3%81%86%E3%81%AE%E3%81%8B-meaning-in-this-sentence) reply in which it's said that `とでもいうか` is a set phrase meaning "Are you really saying...?", and `とでもいう` means "as though"; I'm not really sure if that's the case in the above sentence, though: the first meaning, "Are you really saying", doesn't seem to fit well, while the second is given for `とでもいう` (without `か`), so not sure if that's the case, and while "as if to say" could somehow fit ("As if to say the bycicles where there in place of the taxis"; a bit odd, but I could kinda understand it), `ごとく` means "as if", so it would seem redundant.

The `だ` I guess is a copula, while `の` is used to connect to `ごとく`, but I don't really understand the rest of that structure.

Comment: Related? https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/56849/9831 (Regarding 「～かのごとく」)

Comment: I think so, thanks, I didn't thought of `かのごとく` as one form; not sure about the general meaning of `とでもいうかのごとく`, though.

Comment: What happens after this?  Does the guy do anything with one of the parked bikes?  That information might be important in answering this question.

Comment: He stares for a bit at an electrical bike, then enters a phone booth to call a taxi services: トーマスは一台の黄色い電動アシスト車に殊の外惹かれてしまい、一分半ばかりの間それに見入りつつただ立ち尽くすほかなかったのだが、結局すぐに飽きて公衆電話ボックスのドアを開けて受話器を手にしたのだった。

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`noun + の如【ごと】く` is a literary way to say "like ～".

> - 蝶のごとく舞う to dance like a butterfly

`clause + か + のごとく` is "as if ～". か is a question marker that can form an embedded question or work like "whether/if".

> - 実際に見たかのごとく話す to talk as if he had actually seen it
> - 生きているかのごとく動く to move as if it were alive

Thus, その代わりだとでもいうかのごとく is "as if saying 'その代わりだ'". その代わりだ is the "quote", and here it means "(these bikes) are replacements". と is simply a quotation marker used with 言う. でも here [means "～ or something"](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/21519/5010).

> その代わりだとでもいうかのごとく、何台もの自転車が置かれてある。
>   Many bikes are placed as if (someone were) saying something like "These are the replacements (for taxis)".